# Is there a way to flatten values in a table using rank function?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, teradata

I have a table in SQL which looks like this -

| ITEM | ACTIVITY_ID | ACTIVITY_TYPE | ACTIVITY_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Activity A | Call | Jan - 1 - 2022 |
| Item 1 | Activity B | Mail | Jan - 10 - 2022 |
| Item 1 | Activity C | Print | Jan - 12 - 2022 |

Similarly, there are thousands of Items and each can have one or more activities (up to 5).
I want to run a SQL query to flatten the data at the Item level for all the records and the output desired is something like this -

| ITEM | ACTIVITY 1 | ACTIVITY 2 | ACTIVITY 3 | ACTIVITY 4 | ACTIVITY 5 | ACTIVITY 1 DATE | ACTIVITY 2 DATE | ACTIVITY 3 DATE | ACTIVITY 4 DATE | ACTIVITY 5 DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Call | Mail | Print |  |  | Jan - 1 - 2022 | Jan - 10 - 2022 | Jan - 12 - 2022 |  |  |

The activity columns (1-5) are populated based on the ascending order of activity date.

Is there a way to achieve this? Also, I can import the raw data in Python and can do the transformation there as well if there's an elegant way to do it using Pandas.

**Please note that the column values still remain as column values and it is not identical to the unpivot operation in pandas. I saw the answer on unpivoting in pandas but was not able to solve this particular problem using the answers there**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have the table in both databases. That is why I kept both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY activity_date) rn
    FROM source_table
)
SELECT t1.item,
       t1.activity_type activity_1,
--     ...
       t5.activity_type activity_5,
       t1.activity_date date_1,
--     ...
       t5.activity_date date_5
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.item = t2.item AND t2.rn = 2
LEFT JOIN cte t3 ON t1.item = t3.item AND t3.rn = 3
LEFT JOIN cte t4 ON t1.item = t4.item AND t4.rn = 4
LEFT JOIN cte t5 ON t1.item = t5.item AND t5.rn = 5
WHERE t1.rn = 1
```

PS. The format of the data in `activity_date` column seems to be non-standard, and the convertion to DATE datatype may be required.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for PIVOT, not UNPIVOT.

But in your case NPath works, too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NPath
       ( ON (
               SELECT ITEM, ACTIVITY_TYPE, ACTIVITY_DATE
               FROM tab
             )
         PARTITION BY ITEM                   -- group by column
         ORDER BY ACTIVITY_DATE              -- order within list
         USING                                      
           MODE (NonOverlapping)             -- required syntax 
           Symbols (True AS T)               -- every row
           Pattern ('T*')                    --   is aggregated
           RESULT(First (item OF T) AS item  -- group by column
                 ,First (ACTIVITY_TYPE OF T) AS activity_1_type
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_TYPE,2 OF T) AS activity_2_type
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_TYPE,3 OF T) AS activity_3_type
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_TYPE,4 OF T) AS activity_4_type
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_TYPE,5 OF T) AS activity_5_type
                 ,First (ACTIVITY_DATE OF T) AS activity_1_date
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_DATE,2 OF T) AS activity_2_date
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_DATE,3 OF T) AS activity_3_date
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_DATE,4 OF T) AS activity_4_date
                 ,NTH (ACTIVITY_DATE,5 OF T) AS activity_5_date
                 ,Count(* OF T)
                 )
        )
;
```